# cannot resolve method add () Ошибка при добавлении фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть две кнопки, по нажатию одной добавляется фрагмент с красным фоном, по другой с синим. При вызове метода add(FragmentTransaction) вся скобка с параметрами подчеркивается красным.В чем проблема? Может дело в библиотеках?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
private FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

}

public void onClick(View view) {
    mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonBlue:
            BlueFragment blueFragment = new BlueFragment();
            mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, blueFragment);//в этих местах ошибка
            break;
        case R.id.buttonRed:
            RedFragment redFragment = new RedFragment();
            mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, redFragment);//в этих местах ошибка
            break;
        default: mFragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

}

Код синего фрагмента:

```
public class BlueFragment extends Fragment {

public BlueFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blue, container, false);
}
}
```

Comment: Я так и не понял предложение "При вызове метода ... вся скобка с параметрами подчеркивается красным." Так у вас ошибка компиляции кода или исполнения?

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что ваши фрагменты совсем не фрагменты, приведите код одного из них.

Comment: Изучите работу с фрагментами, в частности транзакции. Потому что ваш код транзакции некорректен в принципе. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Добавил код. Ошибка и при компиляции и при исполнении, хотя код с сайта самоучителя http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragment-add.php.

Comment: Что пишет IDE, когда наводишь мышь на подчеркнутое красным? и ваши фрагменты в любом случае не будут отображаться, потому что коммит будет только по ветке default, когда ни одна из кнопок не нажата. Вам нужно лучше узнать принцип действия оператора switch-case

Comment: И где там в коде `commit()` в `switch default`?

Comment: @pavlofff "Cannot resolve method 'add(int, com.example.fragment2.BlueFragment)" - при наведении на ошибку

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja вот он: `default: mFragmentTransaction.commit();` в то же время ни в одном  `case` никаких коммитов нет.

Comment: @pavlofff, это я автору про код по ссылке :) Копипаст с ошибками.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В активити вы используете фрагменты (и вспомогательные классы) из пакета `android.app`, а сам класс фрагмента у вас из пакета `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. Из за этого конфликт.

В классе фрагментов замените импорт:

```
//import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; - этот импорт удалить
import android.app.Fragment; // - этот импорт добавить

public class BlueFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blue, container, false);
}
}
```

или наоборот, в активити использовать классы для работы с фрагментами из пакета `android.support.v4`. Конструктор по умолчанию в фрагменте тоже не нужен, если в нем нет других конструкторов.

**P.S:** Чтобы селектор switch-case действительно вызывал фрагменты, коммит фрагмента должен быть безусловным, а не дефолтным вариантом селектора, так как там он не будет вызван при нажатии на любую из кнопок, а только когда будет клик по любой другой кнопке, кроме этих двух - вряд ли вы задумали именно такой алгоритм:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
switch (view.getId()){
    case R.id.buttonBlue:
        BlueFragment blueFragment = new BlueFragment();
        mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, blueFragment);
        break;
    case R.id.buttonRed:
        RedFragment redFragment = new RedFragment();
        mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, redFragment);
        break;
    }
    mFragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```